# How to edit the website URL in Google Search Console

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

I've made a mistake and added my site name in Google Search Console with http instead of https.

Where can I edit that?

Should I remove the property and remake another one?

No problems will be happening by removing the old property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can not edit the current property.

However, you can keep the current property as it is and add a new property with 'https'.

You would be able to track and analyse the data for the **new property** from the **date** it is **added as a verified property** in your search console and on the side, you can see the **historic data of your old property.**

I have the same kind of setup in our case except it is `https://www.example.co` and `https://example.co`.

And the data looks something like this.

**Data for the existing property.**

[image]

**Data for the new property added later.**

[image]

Comment: so i should remove site map of old one to no duplicate occurs?

Comment: If the sitemap contains http and your website is in https then yes, you should delete it and update it with the latest version.

Comment: Please share your website URL temporarily. We might find something insightful to share.

Comment: It looks good. I don't see the need to change it. You can re-upload the same sitemap in your new property.

Comment: how u detect that? i u checked my site map or my site?

Comment: Sitemap. The links are in https. Some work needs to be done in the product URLs, but otherwise, it looks fine.